# MySQL - time complexity of finding a table within a schema

Tags: mysql, time-complexity

I would like to understand what is the time complexity of finding a certain table inside a schema. **Is it O(n)**?

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM users
```

I wonder what is the time complexity of finding the table **users**, before selecting its data.

I ask it because I currently have an insane amount of redundant tables and I would like to understand if there is a benefit from getting rid of unnecessary tables and if I am going to enjoy from speed improvements if they will be dropped. 50+ thousands of tables.

Answer (score 0):

The metadata for a database is basically stored in SQL tables.  These tables are properly indexed for fast retrieval.

There is overhead to finding a particular table.  However, having a few hundreds or thousands of additional tables probably is not going to have a noticeable impact on compiling a query -- because the underlying tables should be pretty efficient.

Of course, there could be specific instance-specific issues.  For instance, in a severely memory limited environment, then perhaps the metadata would "crowd out" data from tables, and that would affect performance.  However, that is different from your question.

There are good reasons to clean your database -- maintainability being the big one -- along with usability for people using the database.  If you only have a few hundred tables, then performance is not one reason.